# Svg фигура по всей ширине контейнера

Tags: html, css, svg

Высота нужна фиксированная, а как же сделать чтобы было по всей ширине контейнера?

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

svg.top-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="top-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path fill="blue" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1" d="M0,50 Q60,5 60,50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У вас длина фигуры 60 + половина толщины границы, а область просмотра (viewBox) по ширине 100. Надо уравнять.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

svg.top-icon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="top-icon" viewBox="0 0 60.5 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path fill="blue" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="1" d="M0,50 Q60,5 60,50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```